# How to match the values generated by MD5 hash (Informatica) and Standard hash (Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, hash, md5, informatica-powercenter

Is there a way to match MD5 hash generated by Informatica and Standard hash (Oracle)? The values generated by Informatica and Oracle are different.

Example:

MD5 hash (Informatica)

```
MD5(TO_CHAR(ENC_CREATE_DTM)||'~'||TO_CHAR(ENCOUNTER_TYPE))
```

Hash Value: `132334D66279AF035C5B03B5293457EB10693BBA`

Standard hash (Oracle)

```
select standard_hash(ENC_CREATE_DTM ||'~'||ENCOUNTER_TYPE)hash_cd
```

Hash Value: `1DBED2F180706832F0D138FEB426356B`

Comment: For the purpose of example please refer some specific values, rather than column names. This way we could calculate and verify the hash value. Here we do have a hash, but with not way to check / calculate it.

Comment: @Maciejg - please use this as an example  12-AUG-2007

Answer (score 4):

As shown [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STANDARD_HASH.html#GUID-4A68DACE-CFCF-443B-8651-B6CEAA7C4FD7), `standard_hash` uses SHA1 by default, but you can tell it to use MD5:

```
standard_hash(ENC_CREATE_DTM ||'~'||ENCOUNTER_TYPE, 'MD5')
```

But you also need to make sure your non-string values (like date/timestamps) are being converted to strings in the same format - don't rely on implicit conversion or NLS settings, be explicit and specific.

Comment: "...are being converted to strings in the same format..." -- I've seen issues like this multiple times. Default to-string encoding is not always great.